# PHP curl via curl_exec() different than console curl

Tags: php, curl

Thanks for your help in the past, guys.  Learning 'curl' and have read docs, help topics, and tutorials but can't seem to curl using php for this site.  I have a method that includes doing a lot of curl_setopt()'s and it works for another site, but not for this one.  So I have gone back to the drawing board and have decided to start simple and just do a basic curl with proxy

```
$randomProxy = http://password:users@us.proxymesh.com:31280;
$searchURL = sprintf("https://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=%s",$focusSKU);
$curlBestBuy = 'curl --proxy "'.$randomProxy.'" "'.$searchURL.'"';
$searchPageText = curl_exec($curlBestBuy);
$curl_error = curl_error($searchPageText);
```

Where $curlBestBuy results in:

```
curl --proxy "http:/password:usernames@us.proxymesh.com:31280" "https://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=145131"
```

When the php is run it errors to: 'curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given'.

But, if I copy the curl statement on use it in a Ubunto console, it at least gives me a response from the site saying access denied.

1. Why two different responses from what should be the same thing (curl_exec and unbuntu console)?
2. There some parameter I am not settting?  Is this to basic?  Being basic, I will build it stronger later to avoid being blocked, but shouldn't the php version at least give me an 'access denied' like when I paste it into the console?

Comment: I tried this method in console using another site and it returned the requested page.  The only difference was the website.  In php, though, same thing, curl_error = NULL, curl_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given" and no repsonse obtained.

Comment: You can't use `curl_exec()` with a shell command, it can only be used with a PHP `curl` object created with `curl_init()`.

Comment: There's the command line `curl` and PHP's curl functions, both of which use the same library for the actual work You cannot run curl CLI commands verbatim in PHP, that's the error you are getting. To say that another way, you cannot say `curl_exec("curl -O https://example.com")`. All of that "setopt" stuff if the programmatic way to instruct curl to do things. If you actually wanted to run curl CLI commands directly, you could look into `shell_exec`, `proc_open` or other similar methods

Comment: I got that you can't use curl_exec() in command line, it was the actual curl statement I used.  But thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example howto use PHP curl functions. This is better than run curl binary with shell_exec()

```
$url = 'https://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=...';
$ch = curl_init(); // start curl session
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); // set URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'us.proxymesh.com:31280'); // proxy address
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'proxyuser:password'); // proxy-auth
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow location
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // curl_exec() will return string
$string = curl_exec($ch); // start curl request
if($string === FALSE) { // if request goes wrong it will return FALSE
    $error = curl_error($ch); // return error from this session
}
curl_close($ch); // close curl session

echo $string;
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort.  I think people are mis-reading my question.  I have tried using set_opts, curl_exec() in php, and stright curl in commandline.  Only the command line works.  The other methods return nothing.  What would make that happen?  I have all the same variables/parameters in each attempt and they look syntacktickly correct.  Could it be the website itself?

Comment: Your php code with curl_exec is completely wrong. Look carefully in my code what kind of variable $ch is. You can't use curl_exec() with a shell command.